# Pandas data frame to dictionary date issues

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am having issues with my dictionary.

```
{'ID_Staff__c': 1,
  'EmployeeID__c': '000184220',
  'LastName__c': 'Wimberly',
  'FirstName__c': 'Sam',
  'MiddleName__c': 'Nico',
  'BirthDate__c': datetime.date(1995, 7, 5)}
```

How do i see my date in the dictionary as `'5/7/1995'` instead of `datetime.date(1995, 7, 5)`

Comment: Please add the code where you are _inserting_ value to the `dict`. Without seeing the source, it is hard to understand why the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
d =  {'ID_Staff__c': 1, 'EmployeeID__c': '000184220', 'LastName__c': 'Wimberly', 'FirstName__c': 'Sam', 'MiddleName__c': 'Nico', 'BirthDate__c': datetime.date(1995, 7, 5)}

d['BirthDate__c'] = d['BirthDate__c'].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

d
```

Output:

```
{'ID_Staff__c': 1,
 'EmployeeID__c': '000184220',
 'LastName__c': 'Wimberly',
 'FirstName__c': 'Sam',
 'MiddleName__c': 'Nico',
 'BirthDate__c': '05/07/1995'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simply add pd.date_range() in data

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
data={'ID_Staff__c': 1, 'EmployeeID__c': '000184220', 'LastName__c': 'Wimberly', 'FirstName__c': 'Sam', 'MiddleName__c': 'Nico', 'BirthDate__c': pd.date_range('5/7/1995',periods=1)}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

output

```
ID_Staff__c     EmployeeID__c   LastName__c     FirstName__c    MiddleName__c   BirthDate__c
0   1   000184220   Wimberly    Sam     Nico    1995-05-07
```